# An error in C# Visual Studio about conversions came up that I don't know how to fix

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Below is the exact error message.

> Error  1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'Monopolymakesmecryplzt___stahp.alsothedeathofme.GoSpace' to 'Monopolymakesmecryplzt___stahp.alsothedeathofme.GameSpace' C:\Users\Jill\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SuperAdventure\Monopolymakesmecryplzt;-;stahp\Monopolymakesmecryplzt;-;stahp\Form1.cs   252 29  Monopolymakesmecryplzt;-;stahp

[This is a picture of the code throwing errors up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOzem.png)

Comment: Where's your code? Obviously you are trying to assign something to a variable that is the wrong type.

Comment: Please, please add the code to your question as **text** rather than an image. It makes it so much harder for people to help you if they have to click on an image, squint to read the code, then maybe type the code in on their own computer to text/fix it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that `spaceArray` is an array of `GameSpace` objects.  Presumably created with something like:

```
GameSpace[] spaceArray = new GameSpace[someIntValue];
```

An array can hold only elements of the specified type.  In this case `GameSpace` objects.  For example:

```
spaceArray[0] = new GameSpace();
```

However, you're trying to put objects of other types in there:

```
spaceArray[0] = new GoSpace();
```

This is, of course, invalid.

It's not clear from the code what you're *trying* to accomplish overall.  But the error is simply because you can't mix types like that in C#.

Comment: *But the error is simply because you can't mix types like that in C#.*, that's not exactly true. If `GoSpace` inherited from `GameSpace`, then it would have worked. But since the OP declined to give any code, we have no idea if that's what they were aiming for.

Comment: @MattBurland: That's because `GoSpace` would be an instance of `GameSpace`.  But it isn't.  That's not mixing types, that's using a valid type.

Comment: No, `GoSpace` would be an instance of `GoSpace`. That's muddling the terminology and still doesn't change the fact that the line `spaceArray[0] = new GoSpace()` isn't *of course*, invalid. It could be absolutely valid (but clearly isn't for the OPs code).

Comment: @MattBurland: For all polymorphic intents and purposes, an instance of a subclass is a valid instance of a superclass. (A `Cat` is both a `Cat` and an `Animal`.) We could also point out that if the array was of type `object[]` then that line of code would "work", but I fail to see the point in that.  The line of code is invalid in the context of the question because the types don't match.  What the code *should* do is entirely speculation given the information present.  Implying that the OP could make all of his types inherit from `GameSpace` might not be the best approach for his application.